# Attempting to create a popup window in Android but getting a null object reference error

Tags: java, android

First thing is I've checked [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300284/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-content-context-getapplicationinfo) and ['android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference when notify notification Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197026/android-content-pm-applicationinfo-android-content-context-getapplicationinfo) but I don't think either applies directly for me.

As mentioned I'm trying to create a popup window on android but the error I'm getting is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ca.used, PID: 6240
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:163)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:115)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:313)
        at conversation.ConversationActivity.showDownloadPopUpTest(ConversationActivity.java:451)
        at conversation.ConversationActivity.downloadFile(ConversationActivity.java:336)
        at adapters.ConversationAdapter$1.onClick(ConversationAdapter.java:211)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7161)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7133)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:804)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27416)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

The relevant code is below:

```
public class ConversationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConversationContract.View {
   AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
   private AlertDialog dialog;
   private Button viewDownloadBtn;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
   }

   public void downloadFile(Message msg, String filesPath) {
        showDownloadPopUpTest();
   }

   public void showDownloadPopUpTest() {
        System.out.println("Showing Popup2");
        System.out.println("THIS: "+this);
        System.out.println("this: " + ConversationActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        System.out.println("A1");
        final View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_download_popup, null);
        System.out.println("A2");
        viewDownloadBtn = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.closePopupBtn);
        System.out.println("A3");
        dialogBuilder.setView(popupView);
        System.out.println("A4");
        dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

The error occurs at the line `dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`  and I'm not sure why. At first I thought it was because `this` was `null` but when I printed it out I get `conversation.ConversationActivity@bfca1fa`. I then thought maybe because `dialogBuilder` was a private class variable (I have removed the private keyword) instead of being `public` was the issue but I'm still getting the same error. Maybe it's something really trivial and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: From where do you call `downloadFile(Message msg, String filesPath)`?

Comment: I found the problem, although I don't fully understand it. As you suspected the ```downloadFile``` method is called by a newly created object ```new ConversationActivity().downloadFile(message,savedPath);```.

Comment: Hi @Mark could you let me know how did you solve it?
I'm getting similar error in my app.